# How to use two web methods for two different operations using Restful webservices?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I am using Jersey Restful webservices. I have below web method to get the results.

```
@Path("/persons")
public class PersonWS {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonWS.class);

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Person fetchPerson(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        return personService.fetchPerson(id);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{id}")
    public void deletePerson(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        return personService.deletePerson(id);
    }


}
```

In above Jersey RESTful webservice, i have two web methods one for get and one more for delete with same number of parameters. **In above case will there be any ambiguity?** If not what should be the URIs for both of the methods? Thanks!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jersey decides](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e1669) which method to call based on the [HTTP method](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) specified in the request. If you use multiple methods with the same HTTP method like `GET`, then the choice is made by more Annotations like `Consumes` or `Produces` etc.

BTW: If you use the URI `/persons/{id}` for all endpoints, then you can annotate your class with `@Path("/persons/{id}")` instead of annotating every method with this sub-URI.

Comment: (remark on your BTW : it is likely that there will be a createPerson method using a POST on `/`, given there is a deletePerson)

Comment: You are right. Or there could be a `PUT` endpoint on the desired id. This is going to continue the old `PUT` vs `POST` discussion ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no ambiguity as the HTTP Method is different (`GET` vs `DELETE`).

The same url would also be used to update the object, using the HTTP method `PUT`

Comment: IF the URIs are same then how does it know which method to call? Thanks!

Comment: it knows because the HTTP Method is different. In an HTTP request, there is a Method and a Path (the first line of the headers). The combination of the 2 allows all RESTful APIs to determine what to do with the request.

Answer (score 0):

No ambiguity since the HTTP methods used are different i.e GET and DELETE
And the urls will be same as the param required is "id" for both

IN Jersey client program use GET http method for fetching person info, Use DELETE http method for deleting the person.